# cocoapods can't find simulators, pod repo push fails

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to push a private pod. When I do it, I get this error:

`- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Could not find a`ios`simulator (valid values: ). Ensure that Xcode -> Window -> Devices has at least one`ios`simulator listed or otherwise add one.) during validation.`

I'm running **Xcode 10**, *and* I recently had **Xcode 10.1 beta** on my machine. 
Also, I had regular cocoapods (1.5.3) and the latest beta of that (1.6.0.beta.1).

To reduce complexity, I **removed both betas** from my machine. So, just the released versions. I'm still seeing this error.

I can't imagine what could've happened here. But *something* is out of whack. I'd really prefer to *not* completely remove Xcode, or do something else more drastic. But I'm totally stuck.

Other people on my team are able to pull the code, and do a `pod repo push`, but I can't from my own machine.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: XCode/Preferences/Locations/Command Line Tools; Check that you have the correct one selected. Also check that you have simulators?

Comment: There's only one choice for command-line tools (10A254a), and if I bring up "Devices and Simulators" a see a whole ton. Also, I can run on the sim.

Comment: I trashed Xcode, reinstalled. same problem. Deleted the entire `.cocoapods` directory in my user folder. no dice. I feel like I've tried everything short of completely erasing my machine, and re-installing everything. I've lost over a day on this. _sigh_.

Comment: @Ankur, it is Cocoapods issue  - https://github.com/CocoaPods/fourflusher/commit/b416b8dd6773edffb62e1bc50c395b238ce10399. RP that fix it already merged.

Comment: After installing Xcode 11, pod lib lint is broken again because of fourflusher - The "availability" key from `xcrun simctl list -j` is now a boolean "isAvailable"

Comment: To address this issue after installing Xcode 11, follow @PavloBoiko's answer below and replace `device['availability'] == '(available)' || device['isAvailable'] == 'YES'` with `device['availability'] == '(available)' || device['isAvailable'] == 'YES' || device['isAvailable']  == true`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have Xcode 10.1 installed, _even if Xcode 10.0 is set as the default version of Xcode, the output from `simctl` has a different format, specifically for availability. The rest of the fields appear to be the same, just not this one. You can see this JSON calling `xcrun simctl list -j`. And Cocoapods do not update their wrapper to this format yet.

I prepared **temporary** step-to-spet Hotfix of this issue. It work`s for me.

In log find this line `- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Could not find a` ios`simulator (valid values: ). Ensure that Xcode -> Window -> Devices has at least one`ios `simulator listed or otherwise add one.`

Under it you will see such line: `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fourflusher-2.0.1/lib/fourflusher/find.rb`.

1. Copy name of this file and call: `sudo vi /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fourflusher-2.0.1/lib/fourflusher/find.rb`
2. Press `I`
3. In end of file find line with starts with `Simulator.new(device, os_name, os_version)`....
4. Replace this line with `Simulator.new(device, os_name, os_version) if device['availability'] == '(available)' || device['isAvailable'] == 'YES'`
5. Press `:wq`
6. `pod trunk push YourLibrary.podspec` should work.

If something does not work, please reply.

or

The above solutions will work on a specific Xcode version. To get the solution that works with any Xcode version use the following.
Rather than editing the file, you can copy entire content from https://github.com/CocoaPods/fourflusher/blob/master/lib/fourflusher/find.rb and replace.

Comment: I would like to add someone's `ruby/gems` directory may be different.  Use `gem env` to list your GEM PATHS.  Mine was in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0` for example.  This has also been patch in fourflusher: https://github.com/CocoaPods/fourflusher/pull/11

Comment: `gem which fourflusher` to find fourflusher.

Comment: **Note:** `fourflusher-2.1.0` [fixes](https://github.com/CocoaPods/fourflusher/commit/445535b1f4560e0a4889480ac5c06dc3559e5376) this issue, so you can solve the problem by updating to that version.

Comment: Xcode 10.1 and Xcode 10.2 compatibility were fixed in cocoapods 1.6.0 and newer.

Comment: To address this issue after installing Xcode 11 replace `device['availability'] == '(available)' || device['isAvailable'] == 'YES'` with `device['availability'] == '(available)' || device['isAvailable'] == 'YES' || device['isAvailable'] == true` - source from @JoGoFo . Thanks

Comment: With XCode 11 Beta installed I had to also change line 184 of executable.rb in fourflusher as well:

from 

`buf << input.readpartial(4096)`

to

`buf << input.readpartial(16384)`

Otherwise I was getting a read error such as:

/Users/richard/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fourflusher-2.2.0/lib/fourflusher/executable.rb:184:in `readpartial': closed stream (IOError)

Comment: I thought the whole point of xcrun and the developer path, was so you could use multiple versions of Xcode/tools?

Answer (score 62):

**do below steps it solved my issue For XCode 10.X and 11.X**

1. sudo gem update cocoapods

**If above will not work for your system, follow the below 3 steps, it will surely work**

1. sudo gem uninstall fourflusher
2. sudo gem install fourflusher
3. sudo gem update cocoapods

Comment: Simply updating cocoapods to 1.6.0 or newer should be enough for Xcode 10.2 compatibility.

Comment: This worked fine for Xcode 12.1 and cocoapods 1.6.1 and also XCode 12.2 installed.

Comment: @NickN Do you mean to say XCode 10.2?  you comment [This worked fine for Xcode 12.1 and cocoapods 1.6.1 and also XCode 12.2 installed.]

Comment: This worked for me as well and it should be accepted solution.

Comment: For some reason had multiple versions of fourflusher installed, so I removed both using `sudo gem uninstall fourflusher` and then selecting `All versions` and then installing it again.

Comment: @HitendraHckr Sorry, I meant to say "XCode 10.1 and cocoapods 1.6.1 with XCode 10.2 install." We're still running XCode 10.1 and had the same issue as the reported 10.2 build.  Swift 3 conversions still pending in my project...sigh..

Comment: Reinstalling fourflusher works for me, it seems updating cocoapods is not required.

Answer (score 14):

I got this error after running the Xcode 10.2 beta. Unfortunately the previous answers didn't make the error go away. I don't know exactly what changed but I found a workaround to get it working:

1. Find the `find.rb` of `fourflusher`, you can tell by the location on the error after running the `pod trunk push` command. Something like: `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fourflusher-2.0.1/lib/fourflusher/find.rb`
2. Go to the end of the file around `if device['availability'] == '(available)'`
3. Right below that make sure `os_name` and `os_version` are set. If you look in the comment above it expects to split `# Sample string: iOS 9.3` into `iOS` and `9.3`. In my case they were empty or something else so I set them myself.
4. Also check the availability against true: `|| device['isAvailable'] == true`

In the end that part looks like this:

```
if device['availability'] == '(available)' || device['isAvailable'] == true
  os_name = "iOS"
  os_version = "12.1"
  Simulator.new(device, os_name, os_version)
end
```

THIS IS NOT A PERMANENT SOLUTION!!! 
It's just how I got it to work for now until what changed in the Xcode 10.2 beta is officially supported by cocoapods.

I noticed then when you run `xcrun simctl list -j` on a mac that never installed the beta you have os names like `com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-1` and `iOS 12.1`.

After installing the Xcode 10.2 I still see the `com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-1` but the `iOS 12.1` one is gone. I'm assuming `find.rb` used the the latter to find the `os_name` and `os_version` values.
This is why I set them myself.

Hope this helps other people, good luck!

Comment: Submitted an [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8458) on the CocoaPods repo.

Comment: Mine was the same issue. After installing XCode 10.2 beta and removing this beta version, because I upgraded XCode 9.3 to XCode 10.1.

Comment: Xcode 10.2 compatibility was fixed in cocoapods 1.6.0 and newer.

Answer (score 6):

After installing Xcode11-beta had the same issue:

`- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Could not find aiossimulator (valid values: ). Ensure that Xcode -> Window -> Devices has at least oneiossimulator listed or otherwise add one.) during validation.`

Solved it by following these steps:

1. In the Finder Menu select `Go/Go to Folder...`
2. Paste in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems`
3. Navigate to `{your gem version}/gems/fourflusher-{version}/lib/fourflusher/`
4. Open Terminal
5. Type in `cd` (cd and a space)
6. Drag and drop the `fourflusher` folder (the one that has the `find.rb` file)
7. Type in `sudo vi find.rb`
8. Type in your password
9. Type in `i` to be able to edit the file
10. Scroll all the way down in the file till you see `device['availability'] == '(available)' || device['isAvailable'] == 'YES'`
11. Append to this line the following: `|| device['isAvailable'] == true`
12. Now it should look like this:

```
devices.map do |device|
          if device['availability'] == '(available)' || device['isAvailable'] == 'YES' || device['isAvailable'] == true
            Simulator.new(device, os_name, os_version)
          end
        end
```

13. Type in `:wq` to save the file
14. Navigate to your .podspec file folder
15. Run `pod lib lint` to lint it or `pod trunk push` to push it

If you mistyped something or just want to totally start all over again you should uninstall and install `fourflusher` like so before starting all over agin from step 1:

Uninstall: `sudo gem uninstall fourflusher`

Install: `sudo gem install fourflusher`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, updating all gems worked for me:
`sudo gem update`

Comment: Way easier answer than the other ones, and it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was using `CocoaPods` with `1.7.1`, then I did update to `1.7.2` and the problem gone

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

even i try to use $gem insall cocoapods but cocoapods version is still the low version , at last i find the way to update your cocoapods

```
$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods --pre
```

and then my `cocoapod --version` show out  is **1.7.1** 
wonderful so i fix the question!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this issue when I installed Xcode 10.1, Xcode 10.2 and CocoaPods 1.7.0.beta.3 on my Mac. I run `pod lib lint MyLibrary.podspec` and got the same error message as you mentioned in your question.

Fixed it by running `sudo xcode-select -s /Path/To/Xcode10_1.app`, where `/Path/To/Xcode10_1.app` is the path to Xcode 10.1.

To make sure that you are using the latest CocoaPods version try [bundler](https://bundler.io). Create Gemfile with the following content:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'cocoapods', '1.7.0.beta.3'
```

After that run `bundle install && bundle exec pod repo push` (or any other pod action).

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this for completeness but I received this error and determined that I was getting it because of the fact that I had multiple versions of Xcode installed AND because Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools was set to a version of Xcode that didn't have the needed simulator installed.

Switched Command Line Tools to the current version that DID have the missing simulator and all was well.